# Как упростить дерево if с условием else?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Данный код работает как нужно по задаче, вот только дерево if будет слишком большим, что можно переделать, чтобы не нагружать проверкой сотен if?
По задаче: (приложение Windows Form - C#) когда в командной строке cmd обращаемся к приложению через команду /h выполняется команда 1, когда обращаемся с командами /h /s /e выполняется команда 1 2 3, при этом приложение не должно отображаться. Только при клике по приложению должна загружаться форма.

Код в Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var form = new Form1();
        if (args.Contains("/h"))
        {
            form.Check1();
        }
        if (args.Contains("/s"))
        {
            form.Check2();
        }
        if (args.Contains("/e"))
        {
            form.Check3();
        }
        else if (args.Contains("/h") == false && (args.Contains("/s")) == false && (args.Contains("/e") == false))
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я бы вынес `var form = Form1()` до проверки условий, вам же нужна всего одна форма?

Comment: Пока одна, но это мелочи, поправлю код в топике, чтобы не отвлекало :)

Comment: Если честно, я не понимаю, что делает `args.Contains("/h") == false`, и другие, игнорируют или запрещают команды... могу понять только шаблоны, поэтому сложно сориентироваться.

Comment: Не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, но я считаю, что наиболее правильный подход - не изобретать велосипед и парсить аргументы вручную, а использовать одну из популярных библиотек для этих целей, это сделает код проще и читабельнее, к тому же застрахует от дурацких ошибок. Вот тред в англоязычном SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый вызов `contains` совершает проход по массиву, полагаю лучше сделать один вручную.
Можно завести булевую переменную, которая при необходимости запретит запуск приложения.

```
    var form = new Form1(); 
    bool needRun = true;

    foreach (string arg in args) {
      switch (arg) {
        case "/h": 
          form.Check1();
          needRun = false;
          break;

        case "/s": 
          form.Check2();
          needRun = false;
          break;
        ...
      }
    }
    if (needRun)
    {
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

В случае, если при запуске в GUI не планируется вообще никаких параметров, можно просто проверить их отсутствие:

```
if (args.Length == 0)
  Application.Run(form);
```

---

`args.Contains("/h") == false` проверяет, что в массиве аргументов командной строки не было передано "/h".

Comment: чтобы экономия стала заметна нужно довольно много элементов в массиве. Учитывая, что это параметры командной строки вряд ли их будет настолько много.

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо я потестирую Ваш код, попробую найти в нем логику, т.к. новичок в этом деле :) и если Вас не затруднит добавьте в код еще команду **/s** для симметрии в коде, чтобы я мог увидеть где начало, и где конец для **case**.

Comment: @vp_arth протестировал, отлично работает, теперь есть место для множества команд, единственно, что я не понял, почему `Application.Run(form);` вместо `Application.Run(new Form1());` как это отражается на отображении формы?

Comment: Мы же уже создали форму, зачем её создавать ещё раз?

Comment: @vp_arth теперь дошло :) через `var` создали, просто думал, что это обращение к форме, а не создание. Спасибо за подсказки, очень помогли, неделю искал кусочки кода для задачи :)

Answer (score 6):

Могу только подсказать в каком направлении двигаться.
Вообще любые деревья if-условий нужно менять на ассоциативные массивы (массивы пар ключ-значение). В качестве ключа у тебя string из args.Contains(), в качестве значения либо отдельные объекты, которые вызывают FormCheck(). Либо разные экземпляры одного класса, с разными параметрами. В зависимости от того, насколько не однотипные команды.

Получается что-то типа:

```
//объекты, вставляемые в "значения"
interface Command {
  public void Run(Form1 form);
}
public class Command1 implements Command {
    public void Run(Form1 form){
       form.FormCheck1();
    }
}
public class Command2 implements Command {
    public void Run(Form1 form){
        form.FormCheck2();
    }
}

//это ассоциативный массив
Dictionary<string, Command> commands = new Dictionary<string, Command>();
//таким образом вбиваются пары ключ-значение
commands.Add("/h", new Command1());
commands.Add("/s", new Command2());
//или объекты одного класса с разными параметрами

var form = new Form1();
bool needRun = true;

//далее упрощаем все дерево условий в одну строку
foreach (string arg in args) {
  if (commands.ContainsKey(arg)) {
    commands[arg].Run(form);
    needRun = false;
  }
}
if (needRun) {
  Application.Run(form);
}
```

Comment: `contains<string, bool>` всего лишь метод массива `string[] args`.

Comment: @raingo спасибо за комментарии к Вашему коду, пригодится понять логику их работы. Мне в одной теме советовали сделать все отдельным классом, только не понимал как создать класс :)

Comment: Vitokhv, фигово. При таком расладе мой ответ вряд ли поможет =(

Comment: @raingo, Идея отличная, я попробовал до ума довести, примите правку)

Comment: vp_arth, правку принял. Спс. Но чую теперь код еще более запутанным. Мне не хватает компетенций, чтобы тупо понять, Form1 - это свой класс или дефолтный? И что делает Check1(), Check2().

Comment: И то и другое присутствовало в коде вопроса, думаю это не особо важно. Просто на правах рефакторинга не стоит менять первоначальное поведение.